# regex pattern to match n leading spaces followed by a phrase

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex defined which looks for the occurence
of the phrase `USER NUMBER` in a text file preceded by 19 spaces:

```
^[\\s{19}USER NUMBER]
```

It doesn't find a match. I know the answer must be ridiculously simple
but I just cannot seem place my finger on the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost got it working, you just didn't need the character class `[]`:

```
\\s{19}USER NUMBER
```

This will find all the places in the file where there is 19 spaces `\\s{19}` followed by the phrase `USER NUMBER`.

Your original expression:

```
^[\\s{19}USER NUMBER]
```

Matches the start-of-line `^` then it would either match a space , `{`, `}`, `1`, `9`, or any of the characters `U`, `S`, `E`, `R`, `N`, `U`, `M`, `B`, `E`, `R`.

This is because any character you use inside a character class `[]` is taken literally *(well except for some special escape sequences)*.